# is there a quicker way than this for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I currently have a program using the for loop down below however I don't want to use it because it slows the program down by a lot. Is there a better way to approach this?

```
for key, value in dict(dictionary_notes).items():
    if 'XYZ' in value:
        del dictionary_notes[key]
```

Comment: What data structure does `dictionary_notes` start as?  Sample data would be pretty helpful here.  But no, there's not really a way to iterate the elements of a collection _faster_.  It takes the time it takes.

Comment: If you have to search through *values* of the dictionary, maybe you need a better data structure than the dict you have.

Comment: With the information you provided, it is very difficult to suggest improvements

Comment: How big is your dict? What are the values - a list, set, or other object?

Answer (score 1):

With the information given (which is almost none), the only way I can think of to improve this is through a `dict comprehension`

```
{k:v for k,v in d.items() if 'XYZ' not in v}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use comprehensions:

`filtered = [(k, v) for (k, v) in dict(dictionary_notes).items() if 'XYZ' not in v]`

**EDIT**

As someone mentioned below, above statement actually produces a list. To get back a dict, use this instead:

`filtered = {k: v for (k, v) in dict(dictionary_notes).items() if 'XYZ' not in v}`

Comment: Why are you generating a list when the OP expects a dictionary as the output?

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary_notes = {'a': 'XYZ'}
{k:v for k, v in dict(dictionary_notes).items() if 'XYZ' not in v}
```

Returns: {}